# How do I navigate from a message to contact details using the keyboard?

Tags: gmail

I use only the keyboard, without touching the mouse.

I'm in a Gmail email thread. I want to see the contact entry I have for the person who sent me the email, or create one for him. Is there a quick way to do it from the message page using the keyboard? I would really like to avoid going to the contacts view and searching him by email.

Comment: I only seem to be able to do this with the mouse, by hovering over the contact to get a popup "contact menu" and then there is a "Contact info" link. There doesn't seem to be a documented keyboard shortcut for this "contact menu"?

Comment: See this -> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en